# How to run the selected project from the Github repository in Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin, github

I want to start project Owl from the [repository](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android-examples) after cloning to Android Studio, but I get [this](https://scrnli.com/Z31waHD0YrcGB7).
How I can start the Owl project on my device?
Thank`s for the answers

ANSWER for seekers:

1. Go to File -> Open
2. Then [open](https://scrnli.com/wJZ84Y1NWt4OmL) selected project

Comment: at top of tree there is a dropdown with `Project` written on it change it to app

Comment: I don`t have an app in [there](https://scrnli.com/GXZ9UHt1irX2Ma)

Comment: close this project and direct open OWL from the cloned directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.) File -> Invalidate Cached/Restart..

once android studio restarts:

2.) File -> Sync Project with Gradle Files
File -> Sync Project with Gradle Files" (or doing "File -> Sync with File System")

Edit #2
You have opened wrong folder , open the `/Owl` directory as project then follow above steps if needed .

Comment: Bro, I am trying to  Invalidate Cached/Restart but it is without result. And [screen](https://scrnli.com/nq0871P19Sh5kg)